# Why is the Program counter(PC) 12 bits and not 24 bits in IAS computer system?

Tags: computer-architecture

Why is the Program counter(PC) 12 bits and not 24 bits in IAS computer system? PC is said to have next - instruction pair and an instruction has 12 bit adress and 20 bit opcode, so if it's a pair it should store 24 bits , right ?

Comment: The Wikipedia article mentions a memory of 1024 40-bits words. A word contained 2 instructions. But 10 bits (not 12) are enough to address 1024 words.

Comment: In a computer, there is no relation between the word length and the address length.

Comment: It's a design decision. I don't know what type of answer you're hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

It should be because the PC needs only to point to the memory address of the next instruction's address field, which has a size of 12 bits. The instruction pair is located in consecutive memory addresses, thus the PC does not need to store a full 24-bit value for the next instruction pair